# Compact Framework reset internet connection

Tags: compact-framework

I'm uploading files from a Windows CE 6.0 using Compact Framework 2.0 and OpenNETCF. WiFi is not available, so I'm using a HSDPA connection. Before uploading I check for an internet connection by sending a ping to the upload server.

If the server is not reachable I want to try to reset the device's internet connection and then try again. Do you have any suggestions on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is no ConnectionManager available on CE6 as on Windows Mobile devices. So you need to use RAPI to handle the connection. You may use RasHangUp and the other API functions to enum connections etc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450851.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to go into the right direction. But call me stupid, I can't find the .dll(s) I need to implement this.

Comment: Not stupid, OEMs can decide what to include in the CE image and what not. Do you have a device SDK? How does the device connect to WLAN?

Comment: I looked through the SDK again(Datalogic Lynx) which has a Device class, that manages all sort of connection types and sensors (Bluetooth, WiFi, Accellerometers, Scanner). I haven't found anything on dial up connections so far. But that could be due to bad documentation.

Comment: Normally OEM do not re-invent the wheel and there will be some RAS API to perform a connection.

Comment: RasHangUp, if included in the CE image, will be accessible through `coredll.dll`, see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.RasHangUp - however I see they didn't specify the input/output parameter types.

Comment: I finally found a method in the SDK that turns the module on and off.
The `coredll.dll` is on the device, but not accessible. I can't copy or link to it. Thanks for the help

Comment: RasHangup is a standard call and the args should be the same on WindowsCE7 as on other windows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450851.aspx). For a DLLImport you do not need any copy of coredll. But RasHangUp alone will not help, you need to get the session first.